# how to keep the specific distribution of objects in a diagram after an addition of an element in an XML model PowerDesigner

Tags: xml, xsd, powerdesigner

I use an XML model PowerDesigner. My problem is that when I add a field in the elements of my xsd, the distribution of objects in the diagram will be initialized and therefore I lose the specific distribution of objects.

Is there a way to keep my specific distribution diagram objects when I add a new field in the xsd?

Answer (score 0):

You could reverse the updated XSD in a new model, and then merge this new model in your existing model, not updating the diagram.

You could organize your model XML elements in several diagrams, and update the diagram by hand, keeping the output of the merge to know which new elements need to be placed in some diagram.